# Returns, example, etc XML documentation comments for in-IDE consumption

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml-documentation

Visual Studio does not seem to be showing anything but `summary` and `param` sections. Is there even any point in putting anything in other sections, if the documentation will always be consumed from IDE as tooltips?

Are there any extensions, that show these additional doc sections in tooltips (e.g. like an extended tooltip)?

Comment: Some of the doc tag content isn't meant for IDE consumption, but rather for documentation generator tools.

Comment: @Amy I opened a request to show that documentation in a tooltip too: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/443361/show-all-sections-of-the-xml-documentation-in-the.html